# how to make enemies follow player in arc shape

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm new to the world programming and Unity. And I was working on my first game :) but then I got this idea to make enemies follow the player in arc shape. I have no idea on how to achieve this. pls help :)

**This is my code of enemy movement**

```
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        rgbdy.rotation = Mathf.LerpAngle(rgbdy.rotation, angle, 2f);

        if (distancebtwbody > StoppingDistance)
        {

            acc += Time.fixedDeltaTime * 8f;
            float clamp = Mathf.Clamp(acc, 0f, moveSpeed);

            Vector2 moveForward = rgbdy.position + direction * clamp * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            rgbdy.MovePosition(moveForward);
        }
```

[image: want my enemies to follow]
  [image: current enemy movement]

Comment: Tell them to keep a certain minimum distance between each other ...

Comment: I tried that too.
 "certain minimum distance between each other" if I make them to avoid each other at certain distance it will turn out to be like a molecules in gas.

Comment: you can form a circle around the player, now obviously if you wish for them to be 1 sided and form layers, thats a whole new bag, then on death of one you would need to recalculate..

Comment: is using raycast better idea ?
is it efficient? 
Since Im going to spawn more than 20 enemies at a time.
And its for a mobile platform :(